# Clear "Disk2" "OS X Base System" before USB boot OS X install

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb

Machine is MBP E-2011 500GB hybrid hard drive. Operating system is OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite.

I've encountered system issues that are difficult to resolve and have decided to reformat and reinstall OS X. I have prepared a bootable USB drive to install El Capitan 10.11.1 using DiskMaker X 5

When I use COMMAND+R at startup the Disk Utility shows "Disk2" "OS X Base System" underneath a divider below the title for my installed hard drive.

From what I have read this is a small recovery partition left from a previous install. All of my data is backed up elsewhere and I am installing from a bootable USB drive so I do not want this. I would like to install as if this was a blank, off-the-shelf replacement HDD.

How do I remove this "Disk2" "OS X Base System" before doing a complete drive erase and using my bootable USB?

Thanks

Comment: When you use Cmd/R at startup … that's the partition you're booting from. I'd make absolutely sure your USB is actually bootable before even thinking about deleting the Recovery Partition

Answer (score 1):

If it's under the divider, it's probably not on the installed drive. If you're booting to Internet recovery this is a temporary partition that resides in RAM, I believe, and not in the installed disk.